# MySQL convert to UTF8 without structure change

Tags: mysql, utf-8, replication

I have a rather large database that I am trying to convert from charset and collation `latin1/latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. I am hoping to setup replication to a slave, run the conversion, and then promote the slave when finished as to avoid downtime.

I noticed that when running the query...

```
ALTER TABLE `sometable` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

...MySQL automatically converts `text` to `mediumtext` or `mediumtext` to `longtext`, etc.

Is there a way to turn this feature off? It is nice that MySQL has this feature, but the problem is that it breaks replication because the structure of the tables on the slave is different from master.

Comment: I remember reading a topic about this on here and there was a midpoint of turning the character set to `BLOB` *then* to the destination `UTF8mb4` character set, but my memory is sketchy on this. Also, does it matter what it turns it to? It only effects the data length as far as I'm aware so once converted simply ALTER table to change mediumtext to whatever you want... (?)

Comment: Whether it's `mediumtext` or `text` doesn't matter as much; what's important is that it doesn't change. If you have a master -> slave replication setup, and want to run the conversion on slave first, the replication will break when the master tries to insert new data into the slave. The structure of the two tables will not be the same.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the reason MySQL extends the text sizes is because `utf8mb4` uses 4bytes per character instead of 3 so that if you have the maximum number of characters in `latin1_` it will overflow and truncate the same byte-sized container in `utf8mb4`

Comment: Then I would suggest that you need to change it fom the top down and make all text columns then maximum text sized box, then run the conversion and then if nessecary change the textboxes sizes from the top down again afterwards. But I don'k usually work with master/slave replication tables and It's midnight here so my brain may not be at 100%. Good luck with it

Comment: latin1 needs 1 byte per character; utf8 needs up to 3; utf8mb4 needs up to 4.  So, converting a 64KB latin1 `TEXT` to utf8 _may_ expand beyond the 64K-_byte_ limit of `TEXT`.  (etc.)

Comment: The 2-step ALTER (via BLOB) and the ALTER ... CONVERT TO handle different cases! Beware!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

> For a column that has a data type of [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) or one of the [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) types, `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` will change the data type as necessary to ensure that the new column is long enough to store as many characters as the original column. For example, a [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column has two length bytes, which store the byte-length of values in the column, up to a maximum of 65,535. For a `latin1` [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column, each character requires a single byte, so the column can store up to 65,535 characters. If the column is converted to `utf8`, each character might require up to three bytes, for a maximum possible length of 3 × 65,535 = 196,605 bytes. That length will not fit in a [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column's length bytes, so MySQL will convert the data type to [`MEDIUMTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html), which is the smallest string type for which the length bytes can record a value of 196,605. Similarly, a [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) column might be converted to [`MEDIUMTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html).
>
> To avoid data type changes of the type just described, do not use `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET`. Instead, use `MODIFY` to change individual columns. For example:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
> ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer, but some illustrative examples.)

**Case 1:  Text is correctly stored as latin1 in latin1 column; use CONVERT TO**

```
mysql>     CREATE TABLE alters (
    ->         c VARCHAR(11)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL
    ->     );

mysql>     INSERT INTO alters (c) VALUES ('aabc'), (UNHEX('61e06263')), (UNHEX('61e16263'));

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c) from alters;
+-------+----------+
| c     | HEX(c)   |
+-------+----------+
| aabc  | 61616263 |
| aàbc  | 61E06263 |
| aábc  | 61E16263 |
+-------+----------+

mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c) from alters;
+-------+------------+
| c     | HEX(c)     |
+-------+------------+
| aabc  | 61616263   |
| aàbc  | 61C3A06263 |
| aábc  | 61C3A16263 |
+-------+------------+

mysql>     -- Observation: text was correctly converted to utf8.

mysql>     SHOW CREATE TABLE alters\G
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `alters` (
  `c` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Case 2:  Text is correctly stored as latin1 in latin1 column; use "Double ALTER"**

```
mysql>     CREATE TABLE alters (
    ->         c VARCHAR(11)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL
    ->     );

mysql>     INSERT INTO alters (c) VALUES ('aabc'), (UNHEX('61e06263')), (UNHEX('61e16263'));

mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters MODIFY  c VARBINARY(11) NOT NULL;

mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters MODIFY  c VARCHAR(11)  CHARACTER SET utf8  NOT NULL;
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.10 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 2

mysql>     SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xE0bc' for column 'c' at row 2 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xE1bc' for column 'c' at row 3 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c) from alters;
+------+----------+
| c    | HEX(c)   |
+------+----------+
| aabc | 61616263 |
| a    | 61       |
| a    | 61       |
+------+----------+

mysql>     -- Observation: text was truncated !  BAD

mysql>     SHOW CREATE TABLE alters\G
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `alters` (
  `c` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Case 3:  Text was *incorrectly* stored as utf8 in a latin1 column; use the "Double ALTER to fix it**

```
mysql>     CREATE TABLE alters (
    ->         c VARCHAR(11)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL
    ->     );

mysql>     INSERT INTO alters (c) VALUES ('aabc'), (UNHEX('61c3a06263')), (UNHEX('61c3a16263'));

mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters MODIFY  c VARBINARY(11) NOT NULL;
mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters MODIFY  c VARCHAR(11)  CHARACTER SET utf8  NOT NULL;

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c) from alters;
+-------+------------+
| c     | HEX(c)     |
+-------+------------+
| aabc  | 61616263   |
| aàbc  | 61C3A06263 |
| aábc  | 61C3A16263 |
+-------+------------+

mysql>     SHOW CREATE TABLE alters\G
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `alters` (
  `c` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Case 4:  Using ALTER ... MODIFY; note the LENGTH and CHAR_LENGTH**

```
mysql>     CREATE TABLE alters (
    ->         c VARCHAR(9)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL
    ->     );

mysql>     INSERT INTO alters (c) VALUES ('aabc'), (UNHEX('61e06263')),
    ->                    (UNHEX('61e16263')),
    ->                    (UNHEX('61e162633536373839'));

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c), LENGTH(c), CHAR_LENGTH(c) from alters;
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| c          | HEX(c)             | LENGTH(c) | CHAR_LENGTH(c) |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| aabc       | 61616263           |         4 |              4 |
| aàbc       | 61E06263           |         4 |              4 |
| aábc       | 61E16263           |         4 |              4 |
| aábc56789  | 61E162633536373839 |         9 |              9 |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+

mysql>     ALTER TABLE alters MODIFY  c VARCHAR(9)  CHARACTER SET utf8  NOT NULL;

mysql>     SELECT c, HEX(c), LENGTH(c), CHAR_LENGTH(c) from alters;
+------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| c          | HEX(c)               | LENGTH(c) | CHAR_LENGTH(c) |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| aabc       | 61616263             |         4 |              4 |
| aàbc       | 61C3A06263           |         5 |              4 |
| aábc       | 61C3A16263           |         5 |              4 |
| aábc56789  | 61C3A162633536373839 |        10 |              9 |
+------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+

mysql>     SHOW CREATE TABLE alters\G
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `alters` (
  `c` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notes:

- No Warnings except for the one case where I did SHOW.
- Default table CHARSET was not changed, but that is not a problem.